# from c# server to mysql DB - hebrew question marks

Tags: c#, mysql

my server is written in c#, and the DB is mysql.

I changed my web.config to:

```
    <globalization
 fileEncoding="utf-8"
 requestEncoding="utf-8"
 responseEncoding="utf-8"
 culture="he"
 uiCulture="he"
    />
```

in the client html pages I have:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

in the data base itself, collation is: utf8_general_ci (in the schema, and in the tables).

when I write a insert query in the DB directly (using mysql workbench) with hebrew chars, it's ok.

when I try to insert hebrew from the client, it shows me question marks.
when I debug (client, server or DB) everything shows normal chars.

conecttion string:

```
<add key="MySQLConn" value="Server=myhost;Database=mydb;User=myuser;Password=***;Charset=utf8;"/>
```

insertion code:

```
           MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(mConnString);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand("sp_InsertCategory", conn);
            MySqlDataAdapter adap = new MySqlDataAdapter(com);
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("?pUserId", UserId);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("?pRestId", RestId);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("?pCategoryDesc", CatDesc);
            var result = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        finally { conn.Close(); }
```

Comment: Show the connection string and insertion code, please.

Comment: There is no relation between inserting something from MySql Workbench and from your software. Please, provide samples and code of your client doing the insert.

Comment: thank you for response. more code.

Comment: Lets narrow down your problem. Output the data from the user to a test file (using UTF8 as encoding) several times along the execution path. The first time that you find it "turns" into question marks is the time we will focus on (I suspect this happens early in the process) - and we will focus on the difference between debug mode and nondebug mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing both the collation and the web.config as described, the only thing that I didn't change was the procedures in the DB. 
So, after changing from this:

```
pCategoryDescH varchar(300)
```

to this:

```
pCategoryDescH nvarchar(300)
```

finally it worked.

The solution was found [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/419416c5-d1a1-4037-a5f3-0e815fa6277b/questions-mark-instead-of-data?forum=transactsql)